# Cucumber skip the test

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, webdriver-io

on WebdriverIO and Cucumber I have a test, but it gets skipped every time.

There are some things about deprecated stuff, but I don't think that's the issue.

package

```
{
  "name": "webdriveriotest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.15.10",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.15.10",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.15.10",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.15.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^115.0.1"
  }
}
```

wdio

```
capabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            'goog:chromeOptions': {
                args: ['--disable-extensions'], // Added --headless for headless mode
            },
            acceptInsecureCerts: true,           
            browserVersion: "stable",       
        },
        // {
        //     browserName: 'firefox',
        // },
    ],

baseUrl: 'https://www.demoblaze.com',

cucumberOpts: {
        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        require: [//'./features/step-definitions/steps.js'
        './features/step-definitions/*.steps.js'
    
    ],
        // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        backtrace: false,
        // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        requireModule: [],
        // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        dryRun: false,
        // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        failFast: false,
        // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        snippets: true,
        // <boolean> hide source uris
        source: true,
        // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        strict: false,
        // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        tagExpression: '',
        // <number> timeout for step definitions
        timeout: 60000,
        // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: true
    },
```

dashboard.feature

```
Feature: Dashboard

Scenario: Dashboard page should have the 'STORE' title
Given I open 'Dashboard' page
Then Page title should be equal to 'STORE'
```

validation-steps

```
const {Then} = require("@wdio/cucumber-framework");
const compareText = require("./utils/compre-text");
const dashboard = require('../../po/pages/dashboard.page');

  
Then('Page title should be equal to {string}', async function(titleText){   
    await browser.pause(200);
    const pageTitle = await dashboard.getMainPageTitle();
    return expect(pageTitle).toEqual(titleText);    
});
```

actions.step

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@wdio/cucumber-framework');
const page = require('../../po/pages/dashboard.page');

Given('I open {string} page', async function(pageName) {
    //return page(pageName).openMainPage();
    return await page.openMainPage();
  });
```

I have changed comas, the number of chromedriver, added the capabilities you saw.

The first test that opens the website works, but the one that uses a parameter is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:
require: [//'./features/step-definitions/steps.js'
'./features/step-definitions/*.steps.js'

The name of the file should be validation.steps.js instead of: validation-steps.js

Not it works.